# Change SSIS variable with reference in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I access a read write a "SSIS variable" with C# in script task (Inside SSIS, an ETL tool. Don't worry about the SSIS part. Lets look at the C# only). Its `Dts.Variables["strRope"].Value = "onFire";` Is there any way I could refer 
to a SSIS variable without using this big name ? I was thinking of  -

```
Object var = Dts.Variables["strRope"].REFERENCE_TO_VARIABLE;
```

Now, if I want assign a new value to Dts.Variables["strRope"], can I simply say `var = (String) "Ten thousand thundering typhoons";` .

Is there any way I can do such a thing ?

**EDIT Code example -**

```
public void Main()
{

    object var = Dts.Variables["strRope"].Value;
    MessageBox.Show("original value = " + Dts.Variables["strRope"].Value.ToString());//original value = "Hello World" 

    //Try to change the value of Dts.Variables["strRope"].Value using var ???
    var = (object)"Hello cruel world !";
    MessageBox.Show("new value = " + Dts.Variables["strRope"].Value.ToString());//new value = ???

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `var` is a C# 3.0 (and above) keyword, and you can use it instead of `object` to save on typing and to avoid explicitly casting the type. Try using it along the following lines,

```
var strRope = Dts.Variables["strRope"];
if (strRope.Value == "onFire") { ... }
strRope.Value = "Ten thousand thundering typhoons";
```

Comment: will this make Dts.Variables["strRope"] = ten thousand... or will it just make var strRope = ten thousand.... ?

Comment: I edited the language in the question a bit. Hope its clearer.

Comment: Dts.Variables["strRope"] is an object, so this will make its `.Value` the "then thousand" string. Test it in your environment and print its value.